# actionbar tab's content doesn't displays

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-tabs

I have the Activity class ():

```
package com.wts.ui;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
//import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.wts.ui.MainActivity.OnContextItemSelectedListener;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;


public class TabHostActivity extends SherlockActivity
implements OnContextItemSelectedListener
{

    private ActionBar actionBar;

    protected final static int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        SettingsManager.setPreferedTheme(this);//setTheme       

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_host);     

        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        Tab tabA = actionBar.newTab().setText("A Tab");

        Fragment fragmentC = new MainActivity();
        tabA.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(fragmentC));
        actionBar.addTab(tabA);            

    @Override
    public void StartSherlockActivity(Intent intent) {      
             startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
             //saveInstance of tab position
            }

    public static class MyTabListener<T extends Fragment> implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {
  private Fragment mFragment;
  private final SherlockActivity mActivity;
  private final String mTag;
  private final Class<T> mClass;


/**
   * Constructor used each time a new tab is created.
   * 
   * @param activity
   *            The host Activity, used to instantiate the fragment
   * @param tag
   *            The identifier tag for the fragment
   * @param clz
   *            The fragment's Class, used to instantiate the fragment
   */

  public MyTabListener(SherlockActivity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
    mActivity = activity;
    mTag = tag;
    mClass = clz;
  }

  /* The following are each of the ActionBar.TabListener callbacks */

  public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // Check if the fragment is already initialized
    if (mFragment == null) {
      // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
      mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
      ft.add(R.layout.activity_tab_host, mFragment, mTag);
    } else {
      // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
//      ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
//          R.animator.animationtest);
      ft.attach(mFragment);
    }
  }

  public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if (mFragment != null) {
//      ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
//          R.animator.test);
      ft.detach(mFragment);
    }
  }

  public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
  }
}

    protected class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {

        private Fragment fragment;

        public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment) {
            this.fragment = fragment;
        }

        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }

        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, null);
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // some people needed this line as well to make it work: 
            ft.remove(fragment);
        }
    }

}
```

its layout XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the Fragment class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Fragment {

    public interface OnContextItemSelectedListener{
        public void StartSherlockActivity(Intent intent);       
    }
    private OnContextItemSelectedListener onContextMenuListener; 


    //protected final static int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    public static WordsDBAdapter dbAdapter;
    private CustomAdapter cDataAdapter;
    private Button button;
    private EditText editWord;
    private EditText editTranslate;
    private ListView listView;
    private String selectedWord;
    private Cursor cursor;

    // context menu
    private final static int IDM_EDIT = 101;
    private final static int IDM_DELETE = 102;
    private final static int IDM_INFO = 103;

    // options menu
    private static final int IDM_ABOUT = 201;
    private static final int IDM_EXIT = 202;
    private static final int IDM_SETTINGS = 203;
    private static final int IDM_QUESTION = 204;

    private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {

        // Called when the action mode is created; startActionMode() was called
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // Inflate a menu resource providing context menu items
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu_list, menu);
            return false;
        }

        // Called each time the action mode is shown. Always called after
        // onCreateActionMode, but
        // may be called multiple times if the mode is invalidated.
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

            switch(item.getItemId())
            {

            case R.id.Edit_cm:
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EditActivity.class);
                 intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.fstRow),
                 cursor.getString(WordsDBAdapter.WORD_COL));
                 intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.scndRow),
                 cursor.getString(WordsDBAdapter.TRANS_COL));
                 intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.thrdRow),
                 cursor.getString(WordsDBAdapter.DESC_COL));
                 onContextMenuListener.StartSherlockActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.Info_cm:
                break;
            case R.id.Delete_cm:
                break;

            default:return false;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {


        }

    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_about, container,
                false);

        dbAdapter = new WordsDBAdapter(getActivity());
        dbAdapter.open();

        button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonAddWord);

        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listWords);
        displayListView();
        registerForContextMenu(listView);

        // ================ListView onLongClick========================
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                selectedWord = cursor.getString(WordsDBAdapter.ID_COL);
                return false;
            }
        });

        // ================Button onClick========================
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                editWord = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editWord);
                editTranslate = (EditText) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.editTranslate);

                String word = editWord.getText().toString();
                String translate = editTranslate.getText().toString();

                if (word.length() > 0 && translate.length() >= 0) {
                    Cursor cursor = dbAdapter.fetchWordsByName(word);// chek is
                                                                        // word
                                                                        // repeat

                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                getResources().getString(R.string.word_exist),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (!CheckWordInput(word)
                            || !CheckTranslateInput(translate)) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                getResources().getString(
                                        R.string.incorrect_input),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        dbAdapter.insertWord(word, translate, " ",
                                String.valueOf(false), 0, 0, new Date());
                        displayListView();

                        editWord.setText("");
                        editTranslate.setText("");
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // SettingsManager.setPreferedTheme(this);//setTheme

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }



     @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            try {
                onContextMenuListener = (OnContextItemSelectedListener) activity;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnArticleSelectedListener");
            }
        }
    private void displayListView() {
        // Cursor cursor = dbAdapter.fetchAllTranslated();
        Cursor cursor = dbAdapter.fetchAllTranslated();

        String[] columns = new String[] { WordsDBAdapter.KEY_WORD,
                WordsDBAdapter.KEY_TRANSLATION, WordsDBAdapter.KEY_SUCCEEDED, };

        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textViewTranslate, R.id.textViewWord,
                R.id.textViewSuccessPoints };

        cDataAdapter = new CustomAdapter((Activity) listView.getContext(),
                R.layout.word_info, cursor, columns, to);

        listView.setAdapter(cDataAdapter);
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // SettingsManager.setPreferedLanguage(this);// set language
        displayListView();
    }

    public static boolean CheckTranslateInput(String str) {
        Pattern inputPattern = Pattern.compile("[\\p{L} -]{0,25}");
        Matcher inputMatcher = inputPattern.matcher(str);
        return inputMatcher.matches();
    }

    public static boolean CheckWordInput(String str) {
        Pattern inputPattern = Pattern.compile("[\\p{L} -]{1,25}");
        Matcher inputMatcher = inputPattern.matcher(str);
        return inputMatcher.matches();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        dbAdapter.close();
    }        

}
```

its layout XML :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAddWord"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTranslate"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editTranslate"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/editTranslate"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/plus" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewEditTranslateDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewEditWordDescription"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTranslate"
        android:text="@string/scndRow"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewEditWordDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editTranslate"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/fstRow"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTranslate"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editWord"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editWord"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences" >        
    </EditText>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listWords"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textViewEditTranslateDescription"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

sorry for Huge code, but it dosent matter, what im doing wrong in `onCreateView()` or in some other overladed procedure, why does my content of MainActivity not appear and I cant see the Tabs, what i get on screen isonly actionBar and app icon. What is wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

What device are your using? If you are using emulator, what is the level of the API?

If the API is lower than 3 Android does not support the actionbar. Only if the API is equal to 3 or higher the NoActionBar theme will apply.

In my experience when porting in Nexus one API 2.3, Even when I want to show the actionbar, There is just a thin bar on top of the screen.

Hope this helps.